# Image compression without change height and width of image

Tags: php, cakephp

I have uploaded image using

```
move_file_uploaded($tmp_name)
```

but in second phase i want to compress image size then move to specified location.

Comment: This question is severely lacking in information needed for people to be able to give you proper answers. Where is the rest of your code for uploading the image and what have you tried so far? What version of CakePHP are you using? How do you want to compress the image? Please update your question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

Send Data into this function:

```
$ImageQuality = 50;
CompressImage($Image_Source,$Destination_of_image,$ImageQuality);


public function compressImage($source,$destination,$quality){
$info  = getimagesize($source);
if($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
elseif($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
elseif($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
return true;
}
```